# How can i access Git Repo from Azure PowerShell when im in a Release Pipeline

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I'm executing a Release pipeline, I have a Powershell task, but it says the directory it's not a git repository, I tried using the Release pipeline variables but it doesn't seem to work.

```
try
{

"Initiated"
Set-Location "$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)"
git remote add target https://maliranguesnunezcontractor@dev.azure.com/maliranguesnunezcontractor/PDemo/_git/PDemo
"Added target"

}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]
{
    "Error"
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you are just trying to access git from Powershell. The script is at least telling that. refer [THIS](https://www.develves.net/blogs/asd/articles/using-git-with-powershell-on-windows-10/)

Comment: Can you share your error log? do you use PowerShell inline or from a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, the problem was that the format of the enviroment varibles described in the documentation doesnt work, finnaly i was able to find what format the release pipe uses to change the location to the folder containing the repository and how to obtain it, this was the answer:

```
Function Get-EnvironmentVariable {
    param([string]$Name)

    Return [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($Name)
}

try
{

"Initiated"
$SystemToken = Get-EnvironmentVariable -Name 'SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY'
Set-Location $SystemToken\gitFolder
"Chnged Location"

}
catch [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException]
{
    "Error"
}
```